# I am trying to call a state-changing call to a contract function (on testnet) the transaction fails because not enough balance (account has 0.99eth)

Tags: solidity

##### I have a metamask account with 0 ETH on the main net and 0.99 ETH on the testnet(ropsten
)
The "statement1" outputs 0. As if it is extracting balance from the mainnet account instead of the test net.

The transaction is to be performed to a contract on the ropsten testnet using an account on the same network with a balance of 0.9915 ETH.

As expected, the transaction fails.

---

###### The code provided below is a kotlin code. and all the data inside is genuine. No refereces to outside variables are performed and everything required is inside the function. Comments will guide you through the issue and provide what seems to be sufficient enough data.

```
fun test4() {
    val functionRegisterVote = "registerVote"
    val contactAddress = "0xe2d8a60415adaa2Ba87c44b8C20C9A15e3F9178a"
    val userAccount = "0xE4e609e2E928E8F8b74C6Bb37e13503b337f8C70"
    val userPrivateKey = "66c53799ee0c63f2564305e738ea7479d7aee84aed3aac4c01e54a7acbcc4d92"
    val hostUrl = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/THE-PROJECT-ID"
    val web3Obj = Web3j.build(HttpService(hostUrl))
    val credentials = Credentials.create(userPrivateKey, userAccount)

    val function = Function(
        functionRegisterVote,
        listOf<Type<*>>(
            Uint256(2)
        ),
        emptyList()
    )

    /**
     * the below log statements generates the balance as zero even though
     * the account has 0.99 eth on the test net. The contract was deployed using
     * the testnet ether
     */
    val statement1 = Convert.fromWei(
        web3Obj
            .ethGetBalance(credentials.address, DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST)
            .send().balance.toString(),
        Convert.Unit.ETHER
    )
    // log statements are just print statements. TAG = "VoteContractAccessor"
    // and the rest is the message
    Log.d(TAG, "user balance = $statement1")
    /**
     * Error processing transaction request: exceeds block gas limit
     */
    val transactionReceipt = executeRemoteCallTransaction(function).sendAsync().get()
    Log.d(TAG, "transaction receipt, gas used = ${transactionReceipt.gasUsed}")
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the private key you pass to Credentials.create is private key of your account on testnet?

Comment: from metamask -> switch to ropsten testnet -> option menu to right of account -> account details -> export private key... Isn't that the correct way? I'm asking because, I just looked it up and my testnet and mainnet private key match. If that is the wrong way or if you know any other way, please guide me. Thank you...